# How to connect to a remote database when running the application inside a Kubernetes cluster/pod

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core

I am fairly new to the world of containerization. I tried containerizing my .NET application and used Kubernetes to run it. But instead of having a separate deployment of my postgres database, I chose a remote instance i.e. cockroach db as my database.When trying to run migration and save the data in db, it seems that I cannot connect to it.

I tried running my docker image and connecting to my database, and I was able to connect.

I am kind of stuck in here, any suggestion or solution would be helpful.

This is my deployment yaml which I am using as of now to deploy my pod

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platforms-depl
  labels:
    app: platforms-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: platformservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platformservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: platformservice
          image: sujaydas/platform-service-image:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platforms-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: platformservice
  ports:
    - name: platformservice
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

The error I get is this

```
2023-11-12 00:13:26 Migration failed ---> Name or service not known
2023-11-12 00:13:26 Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
2023-11-12 00:13:26    at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, Int64 startingTimestamp)
2023-11-12 00:13:26    at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress, AddressFamily family)
2023-11-12 00:13:26    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
2023-11-12 00:13:26    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
2023-11-12 00:13:26    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|216_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
2023-11-12 00:13:26    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-11-12 00:13:26    at Npgsql.UnpooledDataSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I have tried reading blogs and digging in stackoverflow as well, but upto now avail.

Comment: How do you pass the connection string to the database that the container is supposed to connect to?

Comment: I pass it in appSettings.json file like this

 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "PlatformsConn": "Server= "connstring" ; Database=platformsdb; Port=portnumber; Username=username;Password=password"
  }


I found out that adding hostNetwork: true in my deployment.yaml file lets me connect to the database, but then I cannot connect to my clusters service.

Comment: I suppose you use minikube? Try this: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/